Is there a way to instantiate a VisualForce page in the background from Apex code and then grab the text from it?
I'm thinking way back and thought I remembered that this can be done but am not sure and if so how.
In Apex, I want to generate some text, so I instantiate a VF page passing it some parameters, then make a call to get the contents of the page as text.  Can that be done?
The reason I want to do it is I need to do some translation work in multiple languages and I need to generate text but not in the language in the running user, in a different language.  The thing that's a pain about SF is everything is always in the context of a running user so it's hard or impossible to get to some features run doing work on behalf of someone else.  It would be create if I could instantiate a page in the background from Apex, pass it a language and some parameters, then get the text from it.

Yes. It's basically

Get a PageReference using the name of the Visualforce page. System.PageReference pr = Page.<visualforce page api name here>
Set any relevant url/page parameters pr.getParameters().put('id', <record id here>);
pr.getContent().toString();

.getContent() counts as a callout these days, so it needs to be called before any DML happens, and can't be called in unit tests.
However, since it's an instance method instead of a static method, you should be able to make a StubProvider for it.
Also, .getContent() will gets you the raw HTML. That's probably not going to be easy to work with. If the Translation Workbench can do what you need it to, then that's probably the better approach.
If the Translation Workbench doesn't do what you need, then it's probably more appropriate to simply instantiate the Visualforce controller (or extension), which is done in basically the same way as any other class.
// You'll need a standard controller if you're working with an extension
ApexPages.standardController stdCon = new ApexPages.StandardController(<some sobject with the id field populated>);

MyExtension ext = new MyExtension(stdCon);

ext.getListOfText();


Thanks.  I tried that and unfortunately it didn't do what I was hoping.  I was hoping Datetime.format() would detect that language from the VF page that invoked the controller.  But unfortunately, it still pays attention to the language of the running user so it's no help generating a datetime text string for a different language.
SF whole paradigm of having no way to override the context of the running user is always such a bother.

@Ken That (formatting a datetime) would've been good information to have put into your question. Classic XY Problem here. Are you looking for just switching between dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy (in which case using ISO-8601, yyyy-MM-dd is generally recommended to sidestep such differences) or something like translating month/day of week names?

We're producing a string like "Friday, August 23, 2024 12:00 PM EDT" from --
Datetime.valueOf(sObj.get(fieldName)).format('EEEE, MMMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a z', tzID)
If only SF had --
Datetime.valueOf(sObj.get(fieldName)).format('EEEE, MMMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a z', tzID,language);
But alas it does not.

The Label class provides a method for translating Custom Labels in Apex in any desired language. For example, you can write:
System.debug(Label.get('', 'HelloWorld', 'fr'));

Which, assuming the custom label is created and translated, could output:
Bonjour le monde!

Of course, the Visualforce technique does work for other types of translations, but be aware that calling Visualforce counts as a callout, with all the limitations that are implied by this (e.g. the Visualforce page can't see any DML operations from the current transaction).

Yeah, I got that working for labels when used from Apex code.  What I need is Datetime format.  And also we have some formula fields that reference Custom Labels and there's no way to override the language there.
